# Different thicknesses for the border-collapse in a table on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, border

In Firefox, I have a table which when border-collapse is applied the borders are in different thicknesses. But this problem doesn't occours in Chrome.

The HTML and CSS code of the table:

```
//HTML
<div id="divTabela">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="4" border="1" name="tabelainfo" id="tabelainfo" class="bordasimples">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="titulotabela">
                <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Data Inicial</th>
                <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Data Final</th>
                <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Distribuidor</th>
                <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Agendar</th>
                <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Ver Detalhes</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="corpotabela">
                <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1">####</td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1">####</td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1">####</td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1"></td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><div title="Ver Detalhes"><a href="#"><div></div></a></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="corpotabela"><td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1">####</td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1">####/td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1">####</td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1"></td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><div title="Ver Detalhes"><a href="#"><div></div></a></div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
</div>



//CSS
table.bordasimples {border-collapse: collapse;}
table.bordasimples tr td {border:1px solid;}
table.bordasimples tr th {border:1px solid;}

#tabelainfo {
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    text-align: justify;
    border-top-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-right-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-left-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #083c06;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

See the table rows in the image below:
[image]

Comment: Please show more code.

Comment: How about the complete HTML for your table?

Comment: It looks like a render issue. When you scroll does the border "fix" itself and moves to another row ?

Comment: @drip, No. When the page is scrolled the problem persists.

Comment: Ok, I had updated the topic with more code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved the problem just changing the CSS code:

```
table.bordasimples {
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border:1px solid #D2DDD4;
}
table.bordasimples tr td, table.bordasimples tr th
{border:1px solid #D2DDD4;}
```

I replaced the border-collapse for border-spacing and changed the color of borders, now my table is the way I wanted, and with a better layout.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I used border-collapse for my table and it successfully solved the problem. However, border-spacing:0px has not worked. I tried Chrome and ran it in UIWebView in iOS. Thanks for inspiration!