# 1px border thickness varies for table in smaller desktop resolutions

Tags: html, css, html-table, datatable

My table is having different thickness for 1px border. This is only happening in smaller desktop breakpoint, working fine in higher resolutions. Attaching a screenshot below.
[image]

My code to apply this border is as below

```
.cmp-sortable-table table.dataTable td {
   border-right: 1px solid #5B3880;
}

.cmp-sortable-table table.dataTable th {
   background-color: #5B3880;
   border-color: #EFB21A;
}
```

There is no table created from HTML, data is added to this datatable through JS.

**Things I tried**

- Replaced border with the help of after pseudo class, but issue exist there also
- This is working fine when I reduced border thickness to 0.5px, but I need it to be 1px

Comment: Can you specify border as `border-right` to `table.dataTable th` too, instead of `border-color`

Comment: Tried giving border-right to th, not working.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible code?

Comment: Does it alter when you zoom? I suspect this may be related to the difficulty some browsers have with mapping a CSS pixel to the screen - which in higher def screens will use more than one screen pixel per CSS pixel and you can get edge effects.

Comment: Yes this differs when zoom in. Now more lines are seems to be 1px, but still there are narrow border as well

Comment: I found that `border-collapse: collapse;` applied on table is causing this issue. If anyone can explain why, that would be helpful

Comment: We need more code

Comment: "_explain why_" - Have you researched that specific issue? For example, have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848023/different-thicknesses-for-the-border-collapse-in-a-table-on-firefox), and other similar ones? Do they help explain/avoid the problem? (You can ask a new question, if there is no relevant existing question.)

Answer (score 1):

This probably has something to do with the pixel value.
Try using the em and/or rem values instead, these values are unlike the pixel value, scalable.

Here is an article explaining this more in detail
https://chiamakaikeanyi.dev/sizing-in-css-px-vs-em-vs-rem/