# Some <td> borders have more thickness in dataTable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using jQuery Data Table in Bootstrap. table is getting fine. But Some td borders have more thickness than others. Don't know the exact reason. Here I am showing screenshot of my table. along with code used
[image]

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848023/different-thicknesses-for-the-border-collapse-in-a-table-on-firefox

Comment: (1) Have you inspected the borders (specifically the styling) in your browser's developer tools (F12 to open)? What were your findings? (2) Can you provide sufficient details in the question to allow us to recreate your issue (a [mre])? (3) Do you see the same issue in other situations - for example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/cell-border.html) or [here](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html)?